# Subtracting of Time in My Sql (Hours)

Tags: java, mysql, date, time, difference

Please Help Me. I Need To Subtract LogIn Time And LogOut Time. I just need hours as answer. What is the My Sql syntax for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the [Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: I need more specific. Please? The link you sent only discuss difference in days. I need hours </3

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks research (even after a link to the relevant page was kindly provided by a reader)

Comment: Thanks Guys! It worked! But another problem appeared. Mind helping me again? Here it is: Error: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '-00:01:46' from column 1 to TIMESTAMP. What should I use instead of timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

you probably want a combination of timediff

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

```
mysql> SELECT TIMEDIFF('2008-12-31 23:59:59.000001',
    ->                 '2008-12-30 01:01:01.000002');
        -> '46:58:57.999999'
```

and hour

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

```
mysql> SELECT HOUR('10:05:03');
        -> 10
```

Comment: May I do the syntax like this? select Hour(LogIn)-Hour(LogOut) from timerecord?

Comment: It says here that Function Hours does not Exist? :( I need this so bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR,start,end)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.90%29.aspx
Hope this helps